# Difference in performance (map(), forEach(), for())

Tags: javascript, arrays

Recently I had some issues using built-in `map()` function on array in JavaScript, which I managed to solve by using standard `for` loop. I've look through posts on StackOverflow to find out where is the difference between those two methods (and `forEach()` which I tested just for sake of it). I understand that `map()` is creating a new array by executing the function provided, whereas `forEach()` (and I believe `for` as well) are not creating a new array.

Could anyone please explain where is the difference in how the functions are executed?

Tested scenario: Frontend in ReactJS receives data from the backend over http request. The received data contains array of objects, where one property is image in base64 string. I defined the function which converted each image to image object (using Jimp), inverted the color, change to base64 and saved back in the array as JSX object to be displayed on the page. Three version of code looked as followed:

**FOR LOOP:**

```
            console.log("before for");
            for(n of result) {
                console.log("inside for ", counter);
                await this.processImage(n, counter++);
            }
            console.log("end for");
            this.setState(() => {
                console.log("Rendered");
                return {
                    rows: result
                }
            })
```

**FOREACH():**

```
            console.log("before foreach");
            result.forEach(async (n) => {
                console.log("inside foreach ", counter);
                await this.processImage(n, counter++);
                counter++;
            })
            console.log("end foreach");
            this.setState(() => {
                console.log("Rendered");
                return {
                    rows: result
                }
            })
```

**MAP():**

```
            console.log("before map");
            result.map(async (n) => {
                console.log("inside map ", counter);
                await this.processImage(n, counter++);
                counter++;
            })
            console.log("end map");
            this.setState(() => {
                console.log("Rendered");
                return {
                    rows: result
                }
            })
```

I included the `console.logs` in the code above to show how I was testing the execution of the code. In each scenario what I got was (before, inside x3, end, rendered) in the same order. Unfortunately, `map()` and `forEach()` didn't perform the whole image processing and what I could see on the page instead of an image was super-long string. The `for` loop didn't fail a single time.

I understand in this situation I probably don't need to use `map()` as I don't have to create a new array. I would still like to know why the result was not always guaranteed, so I can avoid issues in the future.

I want to properly understand how those functions work, so I can use them correctly in the future. The documentation I read on is not very clear to me, I hope you guys can help!

Thanks

Comment: As as side note (But not relevant to your question. ), the `for of` loop **is not** the standard `for` loop in JavaScript. It was only new in ECMAScript 2015. The standard `for` loop is the _initialize, test, do, increment_ style of `for` loop.

Comment: @randy what is "the standard"?

Comment: @JonasWilms - ECMAScript 5.1 :-)

Comment: @randy Yea, I guess you're right! Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using an `async` function inside `.map` and `.forEach` you *fire and forget* the asynchronous action, which means that you won't know when it finished. The `async` function does however return a Promise, and if you use `.map` you could collect them in an array, call `Promise.all` on that and await that:

```
await Promise.all(result.map(async (n) => {
   console.log("inside map ", counter);
   await this.processImage(n, counter++);
   counter++; // why increase counter twice?
}));
// all processings are guaranteed to be done
```

This will execute all the processing *in parallel*, which is probably (way) faster than processing *sequentially* which you'd do with the `for` loop. Using a `.forEach` you aren't able to wait for all results to arrive, and therefore you probably don't want to use it in most cases.

---

If you arent doing asynchronous things, `for` and `.forEach` would behave nearly equal, except for arrays with empty slots (`.forEach` skips empty slots):

```
for(const el of Array(3)) 
  console.log(el); // logs undefined three times

Array(3).forEach(console.log) // silence
```

`.map` behaves like `.forEach` just that it builds up an array with the returned values, just as you said.

Comment: Could not ask for better answer. Thanks a lot, this made it clear! 
Just to be 100% sure I got things right, if I use `map()` with `await` it won't actually await anything unless I use `Promise.all()`, that's how I understand it. Also, could you please explain why using `forEach` doesn't let us wait for anything?

Comment: @Irek cause you can't access the Promises that the call inside the `.forEach` returns. And therefore you can't wait for them. And yes, `await [...]` is a no-op, no matter whats inside the array, so `await array.map(...)` won't do anything useful.